# QueryDsl MongoDb Relation

Tags: spring, mongodb, repository, spring-data, querydsl

I am trying to use Mongodb with spring-data and QueryDsl.
I have following entitys:

```
@QueryEntity
@Document(collection="groups")
public class GroupImpl implements Group {
    private String name;
    @DBref
    private List<User> groupMembers;
```

and

```
@QueryEntity
@Document(collection="users")
public class UserImpl implements User{
    public static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    public static final String LAST_NAME = "lastName";
```

My Repositories are implemented like this:

```
public interface GroupRepository extends Repository<Group, String>,QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Group>{}
```

Every normal CRUD operations were running successfully.
Also operations like "getUserByEmail" etc working successfully.
Now I am trying to get all Groups of an User in a UnitTest.

```
    @Before
    public void setup(){


        roles = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"admin","user","guest"});
        user = new UserImpl();
        user.setFirstName("Foo");
        user.setLastName("Bar");
        user.setShortname("fbar");
        user.setEMail("foo@bar.com");
        user.setRoles(roles);

        user2 = new UserImpl();
        user2.setFirstName("Foo");
        user2.setLastName("Bar");
        user2.setShortname("fbar");
        user2.setEMail("foo@bar.com");
        user2.setRoles(roles);
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        user2 = userRepository.save(user2);
        group = new GroupImpl();        
        group.setGroupMembers(Arrays.asList(new User[]{user,user2}));
        group.setName("testGroup2");

        group2 = new GroupImpl();       
        group2.setGroupMembers(Arrays.asList(new User[]{user,user2}));
        group2.setName("testGroup2");
    }        
        @Test
        public void findGroupsByUser(){
            Group savedGroup = repository.save(group);
            Group savedGroup2 = repository.save(group2);
            Assert.assertTrue(savedGroup2.getGroupMembers().contains(user));
            List<Group> foundGroup = (List<Group>)repository.findAll(QGroupImpl.groupImpl.groupMembers.contains(user));
            Assert.assertNotNull(foundGroup);
            Assert.assertEquals(2, foundGroup.size());
        }
```

This test fails "expected:<2> but was:<0>"
I am confused because savedGroup2 contains the user but if I try to get all Groups with this groupmember using QueryDsl I get no result.

I already checked the database and the users are stored successfully.
I also debugged and checked if the "_id"s of the given user and the user in the database are equal.
I have no Idea whats wrong.

Comment: What 's that mean QGroupImpl.groupImpl.groupMembers. at the end of the argument there is a '.' you invoke another member of the class and pass it as an argument?

Comment: Please fix line mentioned by @erhun and then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: sry of course it should be "QGroupImpl.groupImpl.groupMembers.contains(user)".
Corrected it.
Someone any idea why it does not work?

Comment: I created a ticket for it https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/583

Comment: Any news on this? The ticket says: CLOSED and fixed in 3.3.0.Beta2. Currently I'm using 3.0.0 Final, and I have a similar problem :( (using spring-data-mongodb 1.4.0.M1 and spring-data-commons 1.7.0.M1)